# app is not running on gingerbread and honeycomb with ViewPager and ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I have created  an app which include features like ViewPager and Tabs. It is working fine in in api level 19 and others except gingerbread and honeycome. The application crashes at the time of launching.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{

    public ViewPager viewPager;
    private PageAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Calculate EMI", "EMI Schedule"};


    String TabFragmentSchedule;

     public void setTabFragmentSchedule(String t){
      TabFragmentSchedule = t;
     }

     public String getTabFragmentSchedule(){
      return TabFragmentSchedule;
     }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));}

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });     

    }

    //method that is called to swipe viewpage on button click from calculation fragment
     public void switchToFragmentSchedule(){
        // viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
         viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
      }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

I am getting the following error

```
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.initqube.cal_c.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:53)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-28 13:30:25.425: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Support v7 library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) to use `ActionBar` on old devices

You will then need to use `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` and `getSupportActionBar` Instead of `getActionBar`

Comment: I have added android-support-v7-appcompat to my project now. But after adding it I am getting lots of error in my code.